# Пропадает результат AJAX

Tags: javascript

Имеется код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
function Ajax()
{
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('send-form'));
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhr.open("POST", "search.php", true);
  xhr.send(formData);
}
</script>

<form id="send-form" method="POST">
<input type="search" name="search">
<input type="submit" onclick="Ajax()" value="Поиск">
</form>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Проблема в том, что код рабочий, но отображает результат на доли секунд и пропадает. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пропадает, потому что отправка формы по нажатию кнопки с `type="submit"` идет своим чередом.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="Ajax();return false;" value="Поиск">
```

или

```
<input type="button" onclick="Ajax();" value="Поиск">
```

Comment: Можете объяснить, почему так происходит?

Comment: @Алексей, _потому что отправка формы по нажатию кнопки с type="submit" идет своим чередом._

Comment: @Алексей Первая строчка моего ответа Вам понятна?

Comment: @Igor, не совсем.

Comment: @Алексей Представьте, что у Вас не было бы атрибута `onclick`. При нажатии на кнопку `submit` форма отправляется на сервер, и страница перегружается (если сервер возвращает тот же самый html), или грузится другая страница. Это то, что Вы и наблюдаете. Чтобы отменить такое стандартное поведение, надо сделать кнопку `"button"`, или вернуть `false` из обработчика `onlclick`, или вызвать в обработчике `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: Отрабатывает корректно только <input type="submit" onclick="Ajax(); return false;" value="Поиск">